# How to add a new gripper controller to an already built ROS controller configuration

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently using a Denso 6-axis robot arm to create a pick-and-place code.

I would like to add an additional gripper and a controller that configures the gripper fingers, but it doesn't work.

For practical use, we need to program the gripper and the picked object to not collide with anything outside.
So, I referred to the [pick and place code](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pick_place/pick_place_tutorial.html) published in the moveit tutorial.To follow this tutorial, you will need to set the gripper fingers to "prismatic" or "revolute" and the associated controller settings.

Originally, if you describe the gripper in URDF with the Move It Setup Assistant, it will set up a controller that can be handled by ROS.However, since the move-it configuration file that controls the actual [Denso machine is created based on](https://github.com/DENSORobot/denso_robot_ros/blob/master/denso_robot_bringup/scripts/install_robot_description.py) denso's original hardware interface, it is not possible to add grippers and controllers using the move-it setup assistant.
So I manually changed the move-it config file to add a controller for the gripper, and tried various things for about 5 days with no success.

Please advise on an approach that is easier to configure in this situation.
for example

【1】A method of embedding the gripper configuration in the [DENSO hardware interface](https://github.com/DENSORobot/denso_robot_ros/blob/master/denso_robot_control/src/denso_robot_hw.cpp) and building the controller configuration required for the gripper in the URDF, [controller.yaml](https://github.com/DENSORobot/denso_robot_ros/blob/master/denso_robot_moveit_config/config/vs060_config/controllers.yaml) or [denso_ros_controller.yaml](https://github.com/DENSORobot/denso_robot_ros/blob/master/denso_robot_descriptions/vs060_description/denso_robot_control.yaml).

【2】Leave the DENSO hardware interface and controller settings as they are, configure only the gripper as a controller (with a fake controller, etc.) using Move It Setup Assistant, and combine Denso and the gripper with URDF and SRDF.

It would be helpful if you could introduce a repository that can be used as a reference in such cases.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406937/how-to-add-a-new-gripper-controller-to-an-already-built-ros-controller-configuration/) by [yo4hi6o](https://answers.ros.org/users/73294/yo4hi6o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2022-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to resolve it myself.
I added the gripper information to the following 6 files and was able to solve it.

１．vs050a3.urdf

２．denso_robot_hw.cpp

３．denso_robot_gazebo.launch

４．denso_robot_control.launch

５．controllers.yaml

６．denso_robot_control.yaml

thank you.

---

Originally posted by [yo4hi6o](https://answers.ros.org/users/73294/yo4hi6o/) with karma: 71 on 2022-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0